# Elementary OS Stalling While Booting Up

Tags: boot, kernel

When trying to boot up my PC today, I was greeted with a wall of text that ended with

'''[   0.918392] ---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---'''

Answer (score 1):

A kernel panic only appears when something is really damaged, in my experience I have seen this due to hardware problems. So I suggest you to check the HDD or SSD, just to discard the possibility. If the disk is healthy then boot with an USB and save your files, then reinstall.